# Custom JButton paintComponent Method Modifies Shape Visually? Not Actual Button Shape?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paintcomponent

I am trying to create an application (Java) that includes a map. Each County or state, needs to have it's own mouseover, mouseClicked methods and so on.

The way I am attempting to do this is by overriding the paintComponent and paintBorder methods within a custom Class that extends JButton. The Code and Resulting screenshot:

```
public class CustomButton extends JButton implements MouseListener {


 private Polygon shape;
 private boolean isMouseOver;
 private Color buttonColor = new Color(100,100,100);


    public CustomButton (Polygon shape,Color buttonColor) {
        //this.setText(text);
        this.buttonColor = buttonColor;
        this.shape = shape;
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(120, 120));
    }

    // Hit detection
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return shape.contains(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


        if (isMouseOver && isEnabled()) { 
            g.setColor(new Color(buttonColor.getRed()+50,buttonColor.getGreen()+50,buttonColor.getBlue()+50));
        }else{
            g.setColor(buttonColor);    
        }
        g.fillPolygon(shape); 


    }

    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

        if (isMouseOver && isEnabled()) {            
            g2d.setColor(new Color(buttonColor.getRed()-50,buttonColor.getGreen()-50,buttonColor.getBlue()-50));             
        }else{
        g2d.setColor(new Color(buttonColor.getRed()-100,buttonColor.getGreen()-100,buttonColor.getBlue()-100));
        }
        g2d.drawPolygon(shape);

    }
```

The Result:

[image: http://s9.postimg.org/cr8t6uym7/ss1.png]

What I would like to Achieve (Edited in Paint):

[image: http://s23.postimg.org/aabdtin6z/ss2.png]

I assume this is because even though I am overriding the paintComponent method. This
only modifies what is painted inside the JButton? So the Boundary of the JButton
remains rectangular? Is there a way to fix this? Or should I be trying to achieve this
in a completely different way?

Any Help would be great! I have even looked at programming this in OpenGL.. Which I have very
little experience with! And its taking forever!

Thanks alot

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that with help of null `LayoutManager`:

1. Remove `getPreferredSize()` method.
2. Set null layout to container of buttons (`setLayout(null);`).
3. Set same bounds to your buttons like next:

   `b1.setBounds(0,0,80,80);
   b2.setBounds(0,0,80,80);`

[image]

Also for implements button click you need to use `ActionListener` instead of `MouseListener`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can (easily) do this with multiple components.

Instead you should just use a single JLabel that contains an image of your map. Then you would need to create a list of Shapes that you want to draw on top of the map to represent the outlines of your country/states. So you would need to

1. override the paintComponent() method of the label to paint each Shape on the map.
2. implement your MouseListener code you iterate through the Shape List to determine which shape is currently being used by the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the OverlayLayout: http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.jp/2012/12/combine-five-jbuttons-to-make.html

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CompoundButtonTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(new JButton("JButton"));
    p.add(makeCompoundButton(120, 80));
    return p;
  }
  private static JComponent makeCompoundButton(int w, int h) {
    final Dimension d = new Dimension(w, h);
    JPanel p = new JPanel() {
      @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return d;
      }
    };
    p.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(p));
    p.add(new CustomButton(TriangleType.A, d, new Color(0x6464C8)));
    p.add(new CustomButton(TriangleType.B, d, new Color(0x64C864)));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new CompoundButtonTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

enum TriangleType {A, B}

class CustomButton extends JButton {
  private final Color buttonColor;
  private final TriangleType type;
  private final Dimension dim;
  private Shape shape;
  private int stroke = 3;
  public CustomButton(TriangleType type, Dimension d, Color color) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
    this.dim = d;
    this.buttonColor = color;
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    setIcon(new Icon() {
      @Override public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        if(getModel().isArmed()) {
          g2.setColor(buttonColor.darker());
        } else if(isRolloverEnabled() && getModel().isRollover()) {
          g2.setColor(buttonColor.brighter());
        } else {
          g2.setColor(buttonColor);
        }
        g2.translate(x, y);
        g2.fill(shape);
        g2.setColor(buttonColor.darker());
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float)stroke));
        g2.draw(shape);
        g2.dispose();
      }
      @Override public int getIconWidth()  {
        return dim.width;
      }
      @Override public int getIconHeight() {
        return dim.height;
      }
    });
  }
  private Rectangle rect;
  @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Rectangle r = getBounds();
    if(!r.equals(rect)) {
      int v = 8;
      int s = stroke/2;
      int w = r.width  - s;
      int h = r.height - s;
      if(TriangleType.A==type) {
        w -= v;
        h -= v;
        shape = new Polygon(new int[] {s,w,s}, new int[] {s,s,h}, 3);
      } else {
        w -= s;
        h -= s;
        shape = new Polygon(new int[] {w,w,v}, new int[] {v,h,h}, 3);
      }
      rect = r;
    }
    super.paintComponent(g);
  }
  @Override public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return shape.contains(x, y);
  }
}
```